# Objective c: how to execute a function when app is in the background/killed automatically based on time Intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I need to execute a function when app is in the background or even when is killed by the user, automatically based on time Intervals

Requirement:
After user registered (Ex registered date Jan-1, 2015) , I need to change the status of a functionality as enable/disable based on following time intervals and notify user when app is in active mode or in background or it is killed.

Registered date Jan-1, 2015:
View photos functionality status is changed as follows. 
When status has enabled Mode user can able to see photos by taping on photos row in a table.
When status is in Disable Mode user can not able to see photos and generate an alert by taping on photos row in a table.

First 2Weeks: Disable 
2Weeks - 5th Week : Enable
5th Week - 12th Week : Disable
12th Week - 3months : Enable
3months-8months : Disable
8months-12months : Enable
1Year - 1.5Year: Disable
1.5Year- 2Years Enable
After 2 Years - Status switches between every 3 months.

I am done with the Dates calculations.

But i just want to know how to execute a function when app is in the background or even when is killed by the user, automatically based on time Intervals

THanks in advance

Comment: So you have no clues whatsoever how to solve this issue?

Comment: Ask yourself: how can an app that isn't running execute a function?  When you've solved this Zen riddle, you will be ready for the next step.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the way you choose is wrong. Just use the `AppDelegate` methods to know when the app is launched or when the app will come back in foreground status.

[UIApplicationDelegate Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can call function in Background it's possible but app kill then function not work. Try this code for Background work.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300.0f
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

}

- (void)updateMethod:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
// Your code goes here
NSLog(@"Backgroud Mode");
}
```